# Mirroring iPhone 4 (iOS 7) to Mac without AirPlay Mirroring

Tags: iphone, ios, airplay

As the iPhone 4 does not support AirPlay Display Mirroring, is there any way to mirror the phones display OTA onto a Mac (or even any other computer) **without** using a non-OTA method such as a VGA/HDMI adapter or either Veency, ScreenSplitr/iDemo, or Display Recorder (I have no intent on recording the screen, however the 'Live View' feature of Display Recorder does not work on this device)?

Note: This particular phone is running iOS 7.0.6 and is jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with jailbreak, but I think one possible solution would be to see if you can run a VNC server on the iPhone.  VNC is a screen sharing protocol: the server runs on the machine whose screen you want to view and control, the client runs on the machine that you want to sit in front of.

I did a Google search for "iPhone VNC server" and came up with [this link](http://lifehacker.com/5780908/how-to-install-a-vnc-server-on-your-jailbroken-ios-device) which describes how to set up Veency (jailbreak required) to do this.